# Can any one explain me the below method in Generic Model?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Can any one explain me the below method in Generic Model ?

```
public static JPAQuery find(String query, Object... params) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Please annotate your JPA model with @javax.persistence.Entity annotation.");
    }
```

In this what the find method is returning I think it is not returning any thing but why the method is using JPAQuery as its type without returning any thing and why there is no void in this as this method is not returning any thing.

Comment: The exception throw will exit the method without returning, so it's pointless to add a return statament. Everything you add after the exception is unreachable.

Comment: @Emd4600 you are saying that simply it the method will not return any thing am i right?

Comment: Yes, it will only throw an exception. And if you are not surrounding your code with `try-catch` it will make your program stop. Probably that method is still not implemented, so probably you shouldn't use it.

Comment: Okay Thank you @Emd4600

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Im am not firm with JPAQuery but usually the `UnsupportedOperationException` means that the method is not implemented yet, and therefore only throws an `exception`.

To solve this you need to add `@Entity` in front of the class which `extends` from model.

Comment: Okay Thank you @Einstein